# DeLonghi 3420 jams

Tags: espresso

I have had a DeLonghi 3420 for over a year and overall am very happy with it. A primary requirement was that it takes up little counter space. We buy pre ground coffee (I know, sacrilege). Even thought I strip and clean the coffee basket every time about one in five will have no coffee coming through, or a very slow drip, due to a grain getting through the first filter and becoming stuck in the tiny output hole. Should I use a coarser grind? I understand that Espresso should be a fine grind, but this is an annoying problem.